# edit block in drupal instead of block number

Tags: css, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am trying to edit blocks in drupal 7.x . My base theme is Zen. In block.css I am able to change the css style of the blocks according to their numbers. But its confusing,is there there any other way to edit the style of the blocks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides block numbers, actually drupal will attach quite a lot information for styling when generate the HTML, here is an example for the default `Main Menu` system block:

```
<div id="block-system-main-menu" class="block block-system block-menu first last odd" role="navigation">
</div>
```

As you can see, here we have block name embedded in div `id`, block type embedded in div `class`, and you can choose which one to use.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the [Block class](http://drupal.org/project/block_class) module which lets you add custom classes to blocks for easy theming.